# SQL query to track the presence of distinct values in time

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, I would like to track the presence of each distinct id's from one day to the next one in the following table. How many were added / removed since the previous date ? How many were there at both dates ?

| Date | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-06-28 | 1 |
| 2021-06-28 | 2 |
| 2021-06-28 | 3 |
| 2021-06-29 | 3 |
| 2021-06-29 | 4 |
| 2021-06-29 | 5 |
| 2021-06-30 | 4 |
| 2021-06-30 | 5 |
| 2021-06-30 | 6 |

I am thus looking for a SQL query that returns this kind of results:

| Date | Added | Idle | Removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-28 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-06-29 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-06-30 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for each day and `id` figure out the date when this `id` last occured.
The number of retained `id`s is the count of rows per day where the `id` occurred the previous day.
New are all values that were not retained, and removed were the rows from the previous day that were not retained.

In SQL:

```
SELECT d,
       total - retained AS added,
       retained AS idle,
       lag(total, 1, 0::bigint) OVER (ORDER BY d) - retained AS removed
FROM (SELECT d,
             count(prev_d) FILTER (WHERE d - 1 = prev_d) AS retained,
             count(*) AS total
      FROM (SELECT d,
                   lag(d, 1, '-infinity') OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY d) AS prev_d
            FROM mytable) AS q
      GROUP BY d) AS p;

     d      │ added │ idle │ removed 
════════════╪═══════╪══════╪═════════
 2021-06-28 │     3 │    0 │       0
 2021-06-29 │     2 │    1 │       2
 2021-06-30 │     1 │    2 │       1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And how can you handle in your query the case of non-consecutive dates ? (for instance random gaps between two date entries, ex 25 28 30 31.. ) ?

Comment: @LaurenzAlba . . . I keep thinking there is a slightly simpler way to do this, but it is not obvious.

Comment: That's a different question, but you could add a `dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY d)` and use that to identify the previous date.